# The key "(User_id) = (51)" already exists

Tags: django

ERROR: repetitive record violates the singular constraint "user_otherinfo_user_id_key"
DETAIL: The key "(user_id) = (52)" already exists.

models.py

```py
        class OtherInfo(models.Model):

            user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
            phone = models.CharField(max_length=11,verbose_name="phone number")
            location = models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name="location")
            profile_image = models.FileField(blank = True,null = True,verbose_name="image")


        class Meta:
            verbose_name_plural = 'Other informations'

            @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
            def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
                if created:
                    OtherInfo.objects.create(user=instance)

            @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
            def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
                instance.otherinfo.save()
```

forms.py

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label = "Username")
    password = forms.CharField(label = "Parola",widget = forms.PasswordInput)

class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='Parola',widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='Parola again', widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    phone_number = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=11, label='Phone Number')
    location = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=50, label='Location')
    profile_image = forms.FileField(required=False, label="Image") 

class Meta:
    model = User

    fields = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'username',
        'password1',
        'password2',
        'phone_number',
        'location',
        'profile_image',
    ]

def clean_password2(self):

    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
    password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")

    if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords do not match!")
    return password2

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = OtherInfo
        fields = ('phone', 'location', 'profile_image')
```

views.py

```
@login_required
@transaction.atomic
def updateprofile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.otherinfo)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request, _('Your profile has been successfully updated!'))
            return redirect('/user/profile/')
        else:
            messages.error(request, _('Please correct the following error.'))
    else:
        user_form = UserForm(instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.otherinfo)
    return render(request, 'user/update_user.html', {
        'user_form': user_form,
        'profile_form': profile_form
    })

def register(request):

    form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None,request.FILES or None )
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        first_name = form.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
        last_name = form.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
        username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        phone = form.cleaned_data.get('phone_number')
        location = form.cleaned_data.get('location')
        profile_image = form.cleaned_data.get('profile_image')
        user.set_password(password)

        user.save()
        new_user = authenticate(username=user.username, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, email=email, password=password)

OtherInfo.objects.create(user=new_user,phone=phone,location=location,
profile_image=profile_image)

        login(request,new_user)
        messages.info(request,"Successfully Register ...")

        return redirect("/")
    context = {
            "form" : form
        }
    return render(request,"user/register.html",context)
```

In Django, the user can register before updating the profile. When I add the profile update code, now the user is failing to register. How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simply a matter of not creating twice a `OtherInfo` for the same `User`:

- in the `post_save` handler of saving a `User`, you create a `OtherInfo` object for the user.
- in your view, you first create the `User`, hence you already create the `OtherInfo` associated with the user.
- then you have `OtherInfo.objects.create(user=new_user,phone=phone,location=location,
  profile_image=profile_image)`

This last instruction will fail, because you're trying to create a second `OtherInfo` for the same `user`. So you can do two things:

1. Remove the `post_save` signal handler that creates the `OtherInfo` object

or

2. Update `new_user.otherinfo` by setting the various values and saving it instead of creating it.

Comment: When removing the post_save signal handler that makes up the OtherInfo object, the user gives an update error. I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: That’s because you have a second `post_save` signal saving `OtherInfo` when the user is saved. I don’t really see the need for it, you can probably remove it as well. Or at least check in the code `if hasattr(instance, 'otherinfo')` before trying to save it

Comment: You're talking about my Models.py file, right? I tried all these possibilities, but I couldn't.

Comment: Yes remove both signal receivers in your models. They are not needed.

Comment: Error; The user does not allow the user to be updated, there is no error text in the console or browser. It all behaves well, but no updates.

Comment: That’s an error in the update view? Then please ask a new question with just the update issue. This question was about the registration. Or is there still an issue with registration?

Comment: No problem with registration.

Comment: I remember that you helped me before, thank you so much for everything :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to delete the data entry with id=51.

The error you get is related to database, that the entry with id you are trying to create already exists.

Drop your database and create a new one(If you are not on a production environment)

Comment: I am using the postgresql database.

Comment: You have to do it from inside PostgreSQL

Comment: Actually, I don't have a record in my database. Clicking the Save button creates a record in the database, but the browser returns an error.